# Issues in login with Facebook in yii2-authclient on production

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0, yii2, yii2-authclient

I am using `Yii 2.0.12` [`yii2-authclient 2.1.3`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient) `php 5.5` on production for web app

Followed the docs and made necessary changes in config file, controller file and view file.

Login with facebook is working fine on local machine
But on production i am getting this error[image]

Settings at https://developers.facebook.com/ are :

Client Oauth **YES**

Web Oauth Login **YES**

Rest all **NO**

Why I am getting this error and what are the step to have successful login with facebook?

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer**

Later I made contact with hosting service provider and they are blocking calls to facebook urls, got the reason, thanks.

So there is no error in yii2-authclient extension nor there is problem from facebook side.